# Java :Exporting output into files and storing in a Auto generated Folder

Tags: java, csv, directory, export-to-csv

I have an output  in CSV format :PSD_CSV , i wish to export this generated output into a  file with separated by semicolon instead of comma also  i wish to generate a folder with the name of "Study_UID" of each particular study which consists of the file  PSD_CSV

I would like to obtain this result in java ,any hints are greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job

```
    boolean success = (new File("your_new_dir")).mkdirs());
    if (!success) {
     //TODO handle me
    }

    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("yourfile", "ro");
    RandomAccessFile raf_out = new RandomAccessFile("your_new_dir/yourfile", "rw");
    String line;
    while ((line = raf.readLine()) != null) {
        line.replaceAll(",", ";");
        raf_out.writeChars(line);;
    }
    raf.close();
    raf_out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use file handling read the csv file and replace the **,** with **;** and then write it to new file

```
String fileName = "PSD_CSV.csv"; 
File   file     = new File("NEW_PSD_CSV.txt");  
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);  
try {    
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(fileName));    
    StringTokenizer st = null;    
    while( (st = br.readLine()) != null) {    
        output.println(st.replace(",",";"));  
        output.println();  
    }    
} catch (Exception e) {    
            e.printStackTrace();    
} finally {
   output.close();   
}
```

Comment: `readLine()` and then `StringTokenizer` with `\n`? What is the purpose of that?